# Flash socket undefined property but defined?

Tags: flash, sockets

Hello i am trying to open socket in flash.So i followed one tutorial but i got errors:

```
package com.game.game
{
    import flash.net.socket;
    import flash.events.*;
    public dynamic class game
    {
        var mysocket:Socket = new Socket();

        Security.allowDomain("*");

        mysocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
        mysocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
        mysocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
        mysocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
        mysocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);

        mysocket.connect("hejp.co.uk", 80);
    }

}
```

i got these errors:

```
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
1120: Access of undefined property onConnect.
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
1120: Access of undefined property onClose.
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
1120: Access of undefined property onError.
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
1120: Access of undefined property onResponse.
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
1120: Access of undefined property onSecError.
1120: Access of undefined property mysocket.
The class 'com.game.game.game' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
```

Must i import something ???
Any ideas ?

Comment: Your class should extend MovieClip. public dynamic class game extends MovieClip. Import flash.display.MovieClip for that to work.Also it's common practice to have class names begin with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the correct code for sockets, but it needs to be inside of a method.  If you put the code to instantiate the socket inside of the constructor method, then you will connect to the socket when you instantiate the class.  Alternatively, You could put the socket code inside a different public method that could be called from outside the class.

You may also need to state the scope of your class properties and methods by stating public or private at their declaration.

You also need to declare each of the listener functions, otherwise the socket won't have functions to connect to.

```
package com.game.game
{
    import flash.net.socket;
    import flash.events.*;
    public dynamic class game
    {
        //public class variables
        public var mysocket:Socket;

        //constructor
        public function game() {
            mysocket = new Socket();

            Security.allowDomain("*");

            mysocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            mysocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
            mysocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            mysocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
            mysocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);

            mysocket.connect("hejp.co.uk", 80);
        }

        //private listener methods
        private function onConnect(evt:Event):void {
            //connect method code
        }

        private function onClose(evt:Event):void {
            //close method code
        }

        private function onError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
            //error method code
        }

        private function onResponse(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
            //response method code
        }

        private function onSecError(evt:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            //security error method code
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man but i have 2 errors:1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before semicolon.
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.

Comment: Fixed it but now this:1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Socket.

Comment: I just noticed your original code and my response has socket as lowercased in the import statement.  Changing it to uppercase should get rid of that error. EG: import flash.net.Socket;

Comment: Thanks there's one more error but i fixed it by importing flash.system.Security Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: Not a problem.  For future reference, Flash Builder will often automatically insert the necessary import statements if you use the Flash Builder Auto Complete.